# Calculate the value of definite integrals?

Tags: pgfplots, calculations, integral

I am trying to create a package for `LaTeX`, in this package I will need, if possible, to calculate the value of definite integrals. Is there a possibility to do this in `LaTeX`? Using for example the pgf package?

Comment: Not totally clear to me, but maybe [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) is what you look for.

Comment: Exact (CAS like)? Or numeric?

Comment: If you are willing and able to use LuaLaTeX, you can fall back on Lua's entire library of math functions to perform calculations.

Comment: @Skillmon For example \int_{1}^{3}xdx?

Comment: I will see Sagetex, thanks @mickep. I do not use the LuaLatex!

Comment: Sage is the CAS used in `sagetex`. It can do symbolic and numeric integrals. The documentation for symbolic integration is [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/integration/integral.html). Numerical integration [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/calculus/integration.html). Free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account is an easy way to try it out.

Comment: @JohnKormylo beg to differ, depending on the function integrated my solution below should be very exact (`quadrature` for polynomials up to degree 9). Though admittedly for the function shown by @Fran neither trapezoidal nor Gauss–Legendre quadrature perform well.

Comment: The `numerica` package may be of use to you. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/numerica

Comment: @JohnKormylo my answer uses the FPU of `expl3` entirely and nothing provided by `pgf` :)

Comment: I could say that neither FPU microcode nor expl3 are really LaTeX, but I have to admit it can be done.

Answer (score 7):

The following defines fully expandable (just because I could) integration using the trapezoidal rule or Gauss–Legendre quadrature. The `\integrate` macro understands the following keys:

- `start` the lower bound of the integral
- `end` the upper bound
- `var` the variable used in the function term (should be a single TeX token, any letter, or a macro name like `\x` are fine, but it shouldn't be part of the function you want to evaluate in any other way, for instance you can't use `x` if your function is using `exp`)
- `points` the number of points you want to evaluate, higher values require more time, but can improve the precision of the result (but numeric stability...)
- `round` the number of places you want the result be rounded to
- `method` the method of quadrature, possible values are `trapezoidal` and `quadrature` (if you choose `trapezoidal` the key `points` should at least be 2, if you choose `quadrature` then `points` should be in the interval [1, 5])
- `trapezoidal` (this is a shortcut to set both `method` and if you handed in a value `points`)
- `quadrature` (this is a shortcut to set both `method` and if you handed in a value `points`)

Any of these keys can be either set in an optional argument to `\integrate`, or via `\integratesetup` as a mandatory argument.

`\integrate` requires as a mandatory argument the function term you want to evaluate. You can use anything here that is understood by the `l3fp` `expl3`-module (take a look at the documentation of `xfp` for an overview).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { fsbmat } { unknown-method }
  { Unknown~ integration~ method~ #1 }
\msg_new:nnn { fsbmat } { points-range }
  { Points~ out~ of~ range,~ should~ be~ [1,5] }
\ekvcSplit \__fsbmat_integrate_kv:nn
  {
     var    = x
    ,start  = 0
    ,end    = 1
    ,points = 25
    ,round  = 3
    ,method = trapezoidal
  }
  {
    \cs_if_exist_use:cTF { fsbmat_integrate_ #6 :Nnnnnn }
      { #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnn { fsbmat } { unknown-method } {#6}
        0
        \use_none:n % remove the function argument
      }
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys \__fsbmat_integrate_kv:nn
  {
    ,nmeta~ trapezoidal = {method=trapezoidal}
    ,nmeta~ quadrature  = {method=quadrature}
    ,meta~  trapezoidal = {method=trapezoidal,points={#1}}
    ,meta~  quadrature  = {method=quadrature ,points={#1}}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \integratesetup { m }
  { \ekvcChange \__fsbmat_integrate_kv:nn {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\integrate { O{} m }
  { \__fsbmat_integrate_kv:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_eval:n { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNn { nNe }
\cs_new:Npn \fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal:Nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    % #1: variable
    % #2: start
    % #3: end
    % #4: points
    % #5: round
    % #6: function
    \fp_eval:e
      {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne
        \__fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal:nnNnnnn
          {
            { \fp_eval:n { ( #3 - #2 ) / ( #4 - 1 ) } }
            { \int_eval:n { #4 - 2 } }
          }
          #1 {#2} {#3} {#5} {#6}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \fsbmat_evaluate:nNn #1#2#3
  { \fp_eval:e { \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNn {#3} #2 { (#1) } } }
\cs_new:Npn \__fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal:nnNnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    round
      (
        #1 *
        (
          0.5 *
          (
            \fsbmat_evaluate:nNn {#4} #3 {#7}
            + \fsbmat_evaluate:nNn {#5} #3 {#7}
          )
          \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \__fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal_loop:nnnNnn
            {
              {1}
              { \fp_eval:n { #4 + #1 } }
            }
            {#2} #3 {#7} {#1}
        )
        ,#6
      )
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal_loop:nnnNnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF {#1} > {#3}
      {
        + \fsbmat_evaluate:nNn {#2} #4 {#5}
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \__fsbmat_integrate_trapezoidal_loop:nnnNnn
          {
            { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } }
            { \fp_eval:n { #2 + #6 } }
          }
        {#3} #4 {#5} {#6}
      }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \evaluatefunction \fsbmat_evaluate:nNn


\cs_new:Npn \fsbmat_integrate_quadrature:Nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    % #1: variable
    % #2: start
    % #3: end
    % #4: points
    % #5: round
    % #6: function
    \fp_eval:e
      {
        \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
          { \int_compare_p:nNn {#4} < 1 }
          { \int_compare_p:nNn {#4} > 5 }
          {
            \msg_expandable_error:nn { fsbmat } { points-range }
            0
          }
          {
            round
              (
                \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
                  { \fp_compare_p:nNn {#2} = {-1} }
                  { \fp_compare_p:nNn {#3} = {1} }
                  {
                    \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_aux:vNn
                      { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_ #4 _tl }
                      #1 {#6}
                  }
                  {
                    (#3 - #2) / 2 * (
                      \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_aux:vNe
                        { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_ #4 _tl }
                        #1
                        {
                          \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNe {#6} #1
                            {
                              (
                                \fp_eval:n { (#3 - #2) / 2 } * \exp_not:N #1
                                + \fp_eval:n { (#3 + #2) / 2 }
                              )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                  }
                ,#5
              )
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_aux:nNn #1#2#3
  { \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN #2 {#3} #1 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_aux:nNn { v, vNe }
\cs_new:Npn \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    + (#4) * (\fsbmat_evaluate:nNn {#3} #1 {#2})
    #5 #1 {#2}
  }

% points and weights according to
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature
\tl_const:cx { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_1_tl }
  { {0} {2} \exp_not:N \use_none:nn }
\tl_const:cx { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_2_tl }
  {
      { -\fp_eval:n { 1/sqrt(3) } } {1}
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { 1/sqrt(3) } } {1}
    \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
  }
\tl_const:cx { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_3_tl }
  {
      { -\fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/5) } } { \fp_eval:n { 5/9 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {0} { \fp_eval:n { 8/9 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/5) } } { \fp_eval:n { 5/9 } }
    \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
  }
\tl_const:cx { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_4_tl }
  {
      { -\fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/7 + 2/7*sqrt(6/5)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (18-sqrt(30))/36 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      { -\fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/7 - 2/7*sqrt(6/5)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (18+sqrt(30))/36 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/7 - 2/7*sqrt(6/5)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (18+sqrt(30))/36 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { sqrt(3/7 + 2/7*sqrt(6/5)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (18-sqrt(30))/36 } }
    \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
  }
\tl_const:cx { c__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_points_5_tl }
  {
      { -\fp_eval:n { 1/3 * sqrt(5 + 2*sqrt(10/7)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (322 - 13*sqrt(70)) / 900 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      { -\fp_eval:n { 1/3 * sqrt(5 - 2*sqrt(10/7)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (322 + 13*sqrt(70)) / 900 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {0}
      {  \fp_eval:n { 128/225 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { 1/3 * sqrt(5 - 2*sqrt(10/7)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (322 + 13*sqrt(70)) / 900 } }
    \exp_not:N \__fsbmat_integrate_quadrature_point:NnnnN
      {  \fp_eval:n { 1/3 * sqrt(5 + 2*sqrt(10/7)) } }
      {  \fp_eval:n { (322 - 13*sqrt(70)) / 900 } }
    \exp_not:N \use_none:nn
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
A simple example
\[
  \int_0^1 x\,\mathrm{d}x = \integrate[points=2]{x}
    = \integrate[quadrature=1]{x}
\]
and something more difficult
\[
  \int_1^5 \frac{1}{\exp{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
    \approx \integrate[var=\x,start=1,end=5,round=10,quadrature=5]{1/exp(\x)}
    \approx \integrate[var=\x,start=1,end=5,round=10]{1/exp(\x)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Prints:

[image]

Note that this might turn out to be very numerical instable (depending on the function you want to evaluate), for instance, trying to calculate the integral shown by @Fran (by splitting it up into parts to increase the accuracy, nothing much happens for big values):

```
\fpeval
  {
    \integrate[start=0.001,end=10,points=501]{1/((1+x)*sqrt(x))}
    + \integrate[start=29.98,end=10000,points=500]{1/((1+x)*sqrt(x))}
  }
```

yields the result 2.98 (a bit off, innit?), playing with the values and splitting the first interval once more you can improve this to

```
\fpeval
  {
    \integrate[start=1e-5,end=1,points=501]{1/((1+x)*sqrt(x))}
    + \integrate[start=1.018,end=10,points=500]{1/((1+x)*sqrt(x))}
    + \integrate[start=29.98,end=10000,points=500]{1/((1+x)*sqrt(x))}
  }
```

yielding 3.12. But further reducing the first intervals lower bound worsens the result due to the numeric unstableness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and dedication to writing the code. I believe it will help a lot!

Comment: @fsbmat just remember this is relatively stupid code, the user should still have some basic understandings of the limits of this and use it correctly/on the right category of problems. If you have access to a CAS that is preferable in most cases.

Comment: I'm looking into the possibility of using SageTex, but was very grateful for its availability!

Answer (score 4):

Not idea of how to do this using just LaTeX, but with the help of `knitr` seems easy:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}

\[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}} \dd{x}\]

<<echo=F>>=
integrand <- function(x) {1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))}
a <- integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
@

The result is roughly \Sexpr{round(a$value,2)} 
(more exactly \Sexpr{a$value}) with an absolute 
error of \Sexpr{signif(a$abs.error,2)}.  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Determining the value of integrals using just LaTeX is unlikely to work unless you are able to put some restriction on the integrals that arrive (for example, the integrand is always a polynomial with degree less than n). In general LaTeX has problems with difficult calculations. The `sagetex` package which gives you access to the [Sage CAS](https://www.sagemath.org/) as well as the Python programming language so it can easily solve integrals. The CAS is not part of LaTeX so creating a package off of it won't work. Here is sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,amsmath}
\begin{document}
The sagetex package gives you access to the Sage CAS along with the Python
programming language.
\begin{sagesilent}
from sage.symbolic.integration.integral import indefinite_integral
f=x/3
g(x)= 1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))
\end{sagesilent}
Using Sage we can calculate integrals that can be solved using symbolic integration. For example: \[\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{3} dx = \sage{f.integral(x)}\biggr\rvert_{0}^{1}=\sage{f.integral(x, 0, 1)}\].

Sage can calculate integrals numerically as well. For example:
\[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt(x)} \approx \sage{numerical_integral(g, 0, +Infinity)[0]}\]
The error estimate for the answer is $\sage{numerical_integral(g, 0, +Infinity)[1]}$.
\end{document}
```

The output running in Cocalc is:
[image]

My comment under your question has links to Sage symbolic/numerical integration as well as Cocalc.