# Сalculate the integral

Tags: integral

There is a command to calculate the probability distribution function.

I need to calculate the probability distribution density, for which I have to numerically find the integral of the first function. How can I record this in a new command?

```
\newcommand\PDF[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}

\newcommand\PDD[2]{int {1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}} % ???
\newcommand\PDD[2]{int PDF} % ???
```

Comment: AFAIK, Latex is not suitable for calculating these kinds of functions. Better use a dedicated CAS software for that purpose.

Comment: can I use a package "numerica" for this?

Comment: Evaluating the normal or Gaussian integral directly is not easy, as there is no known closed form soiution for the associated integral equation. As a way out, consider using a series approximation. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355599/5001), I suggest using the approximation proposed by [Abramovity and Stegun (1964)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888165/29946) to calculate the entries in a table of cdf (cumulative distribution function) values. (The A&S approximation evaluates a polynomial of order 5.)

Comment: Taking a look at the function it is rather well-behaved for *b* > 0, so as long as you don't want to integrate along *b* with values nearing zero you'd be fine with the `\integrate` macro presented in my answer there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662100/117050

Comment: Skillmon, I copied your code completely, but it doesn't work. Error in line "\usepackage{expkv-cs}"